# How to design backward compatibility and not turn your code into a mess?

Tags: web-services, versioning, compatibility, maintainability

I am developing a Java-based RESTful web application intended to be a centerpiece for its various client apps. Those client-apps can operate on the same assets in the main system (e.g. client-app A creates assets in main system, and client-app B fetches them from the system). We've rolled out the */v1/* API version and develop new features in */v2/*. The requirement is to release v2, while still supporting backwards compatibility for v1 for some period of time, until all client-apps are ported to v2. The idea behind this requirement is that client-apps potentially written against different API versions should still be able to cooperate on the same assets.

Currently, we cover both API versions within a single instance of the system. While for some minor changes in HTTP API, it usually suffices to provide a new controller (sth like a bridge pattern), for slightly bigger changes it seems best to write a new controller & service layer (and hopefully both versions will "meet" at some level, reusing a common set of functionalities).

However, there are much broader changes to come. What's more, the main system is not just a dumb CRUD, it's rather a complex multi-component network, integrated with a handful of external services, involving some async jobs' processing, etc. Certainly it's all but a convenient place for keeping backward compatibility behavior-wise.

**Are there any best practises to keep backwards compatibility of API & behavior behind it, while not turning the code into a mess?**

We do care about the quality of code, and hate polluting it with copy-paste-adjust classes and maintaining duplicate/parallel feature implementations. And yes, we have already divided the java packages for v1 and v2.

Also, we'd like to avoid the situation where the old version's code ties our hands and keeps us from redesigning the new version's architecture, just for the sake of simplicity of keeping this back compatibility.

Comment: Make sure you have good testing procedure, when you make changes in v2 it shouldn't affect the output of v1.